# FormatException appears when trying to convert a string to Int16

Tags: c#, winforms

The program is supposed to take a positive number from `textbox1.Text` and send it to the constructor `HR` form to use it as array size (handled error with try catch) but when I run the program it gives error.

```
//first form(info)
HR frm = new HR(textBox1.Text);
frm.show();
this.close();
//2nd form(HR)
static int size = 0;
public HR(string emplyee_num)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    size = Convert.ToInt16(emplyee_num);//Error appear her instead
}
```

However, I tried to send the string then convert it in HR form instead of send it as shown in picture it gives error in the line for converting.

[image: Error in original code]

How can I fix that error and what is the reason for it being thrown?

Comment: As you can see from your own picture the value of TextBox1.Text is an empty string and this cannot be converted to an int16. Probably you need to add some check on this value before calling the HR constructor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `FormatException` is thrown because text in the input control is not a valid number.

It would be better to try parsing the input first and only create the form if the input is valid like this:

```
Int16 size = 0;
try
{
     size = Convert.ToInt16(textBox1.Text));
}
catch(FormatException)
{
     // Handle exception
}

if(size > 0)
{
     HR frm = new HR(size);
     frm.show();
     this.close();
}
else
{
     // Handle error
}
```

Remember to update `HR` constructor definition:

```
public HR(Int16 emplyee_num)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    size = emplyee_num;
}
```

Comment: Do not drive code using Exceptions. In particular when the possible error is well handled by more correct methods like Int16.TryParse